# Testing an Angular 2 component with createEmbeddedView

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-components

I have a component with a template that displays conditionally like so:

```
@Component({
    selector: "presentation",
    template: "<template #tpl><!-- HTML --></template>"
})
export class Presentation implements AfterViewInit {

    @ViewChild('tpl') template: TemplateRef<any>;
    constructor(private view: ViewContainerRef) {}

    ngAfterViewInit() {
       this.view.createEmbeddedView(this.template); 
    }
}
```

I am trying to write a test but as soon as I call

```
it("should launch card in practice mode", () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
}
```

I get:

```
Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You ever solve this? Having the same issue.